# for class wp_widget, in what order are the member functions called?

Tags: widgets

When a widget is used, in what order are the members used? Obviously, `__construct` is first, but what happens next? function `widget()`? function `form()`?

Which comes first, the chicken or the egg?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell the order in which these functions are called, because they're used in different contexts.

[`WP_Widget`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/#developing-widgets) class has 4 methods:

- **`__construct`** - it constructs the widget, so it's always run first
- **`widget`** - it should output the content of given widget, so it's used on front-end in sidebar, when the widget is printed
- **`form`** - it outputs the options of given widget in admin area, so it's used in admin, when you edit the widget
- **`update`** - it processes the options form and saves the options, so it's used in admin, when you save the widget options

Answer (score 0):

By using logging, I found out that if it has not been constructed, then function form is called, then function widget.